# How can I remove the line in a staticBoxSizer in wxPython 2.8?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I am modifying an existing code base that has a GUI with a staticBoxSizer. One of the features of staticBoxSizer is that it includes a decorative border line around the sizer, and a label at the top. In the image below, we have two staticBoxSizers, one with label 'Name:' and the other with label 'buttons:'

[image]

Is there a simple setting I can change so that the bordering line is either gone or of a different color? I need to keep the label however

The [staticBoxSizer](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticBoxSizer-class.html) uses a [staticBox](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticBox-class.html) object as an argument to the constructor.  I think I can do this just fine by just using [boxSizers](https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.agw.buttonpanel.BoxSizer-class.html), but that would involve some more reworking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that you are going to have to re-word/clarify this question.

Comment: Ok, how's this?

Comment: Probably best done with 2 gridsizers or flexgridsizers, added to a mainsizer defined as a boxsizer(wx.VERTICAL) or if you are running Linux Mint, choose the Mint-X theme and it gets rid of the line around the box due to a bug ;)

Answer (score 1):

A `wx.StaticBoxSizer` is intended to be used with a `wx.StaticBox`.  If you don't want that then use a different kind of sizer, or sizers,  adding a `wx.StaticText` for the label.